# python bot Instagram Email

Tags: python, bots, instagram

I am working on a Instagram account creator and I am stuck. When you create an Instagram account you need an Email. I am using ProtonMail and I am using Selenium to do my web automating but when I get to the step where it asks you to input the username you want, my code can't find the box.
Right now the code that selects the username box looks like this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(username)
self.driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
self.driver.find_element_by_id('passwordc').send_keys(password)
```

and the error looks like this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="username"]"}
```

but the id for the username is correct:
[id for username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIxSR.png)

Also the two lines of code for passwords works, it is just the username that doesn't.

I tried to find the username box by its class name but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using JQuery in your browsers inspect element JS console to validate your selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future protonmail questions. It is a different `iframe` that is why the usual methods don't work. We need to switch the `iframe`

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    # chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='C:/bin/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://protonmail.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-short' and @href='signup']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//p[text()='Basic account with limited features']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right' and @id='freePlan']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='usernameWrap']//iframe[@title='Registration form']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='input' and @id='username']"))).send_keys("username")
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still doesn't work. The error says: 
        selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
        Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".f0n8F "}

Comment: my username is for ProtonMail not Instagram.

Comment: @peterqiu Ok..Done it. Check Please.It's a different `iframe` that is the issue.